# angular ng-repeat not updating if called from onclick function of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to fill the value of select from ng-repeat but it is not updating any value in select but same thing i am calling from ng-click function it is updating the select i am not able to figure out what is the issue.

below is my code when using onclick:

```
<label><input type="radio" ng-model="tableSource.name" id="browseDataLov" name="typeOfData" value="lov" onclick="callAct()">xyz </label>
<label><input type="radio" ng-model="tableSource.name" id="browseDataInside" name="typeOfData" value="Others" ng-click="aiWidgetOthers('table')">
        Others</label>

<select  id="Assign" name="Assign" class="" multiple size="7">
<option ng-repeat="item in items" data-id="{{item .id}}" data-format="{{item .format}}" value="{{item .name}}">{{item .name}}</option>
    </select>

<div id="testDiv" ng-controller="dbCtrl"></div>

 function callAct(){
              angular.element(document.getElementById('testDiv')).scope().wid();
      angular.element(document.getElementById('testDiv')).scope().$apply();
  }

app.controller('dbCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.wid= function(){
 $scope.items = [{
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "xyz",
   "format" : "xml"
     },{
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "abc",
   "format" : "xml"
     }]
});
```

below is my code when using ng-click:

```
<label><input type="radio" ng-model="tableSource.name" id="browseDataLov" name="typeOfData" value="lov" ng-click="wid()">xyz </label>
```

but due to some reason i need to call it from onclick function because at first time when i am coming to this page ng-click works perfectly but as soon as i route the page and come back again the function stops working as this select is inside jquery dialog box

Comment: can you post fiddle ?

Comment: Why do you even want to mix jQuerry with Angular?

Comment: because when i am routing the page coming back again to this page it ng-click function stops working. only the functions which are under jquery dialog box all that functions stops working other functions works fine. thats the reason i need to use jquery with angularjs